# Check if EditText is empty

Tags: android

I am making a math app. I have two arrays with two sets of numbers. I make the app choose a random number from each array. The app displays that two numbers in a `TextView`. It asks the user to type in a `EditText` what the addition of the numbers is. Then when the user presses "Submit", the app will then tell the user if they are right or wrong.

The app works, but I have one main problem. If the user does not type anything in the `EditText` and presses "Submit", the app force closes. I have looked at other questions asking how to check if a `EditText` is empty. I tried different methods but it still does not work.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button submitb, startb, idkb;
EditText et;
TextView tv, rig, wron;

int arrone[] = { 24, 54, 78, 96, 48, 65, 32, 45, 95, 13, 41, 55, 33, 22,
        71, 5, 22, 17, 13, 29, 63, 72, 14, 81, 7 }; // One Set of Numbers//
int arrtwo[] = { 121, 132, 147, 79, 82, 723, 324, 751, 423, 454, 448,
        524, 512, 852, 845, 485, 775, 186, 99 }; // Another set of Numbers//
int random1, random2, add;
int wrong = 0;
int right = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list();
    startb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int num = (int) (Math.random() * 25);
            int mun = (int) (Math.random() * 19);
            random1 = arrone[num];
            random2 = arrtwo[mun];
            String yu = (random1 + " + " + random2 + " =");
            tv.setText(yu);
            et.setHint("");
            idkb.setVisibility(0);
            startb.setText("Next Question");

        }
    });

    startb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int bread2 = 0;
            if (bread2 == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You didn't answer the question!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            int swag = random1 + random2;
            String bread = et.getText().toString();
            bread2 = Integer.parseInt(bread);

            if (bread2 == swag) {
                startb.setText("Next Question");
                tv.setText("Correct");
                et.setText("");
                et.setHint("Click Next Question");
                right++;
                rig.setText("Right:" + right);
                rig.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#14df11"));
                bread2 = 0;
            }

            else if (bread2 == 0) {
                tv.setText("Wrong, the correct answer is " + swag + ".");

                startb.setText("Next Question");
                et.setText("");
                tv.setHint("Click Next Question");
                wrong++;
                wron.setText("Wrong:" + wrong);
                wron.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                bread2 = 0;
            }

            else {
                tv.setText("Wrong, the correct answer is " + swag + ".");

                startb.setText("Next Question");
                et.setText("");
                et.setHint("Click Next Question");
                wrong++;
                wron.setText("Wrong:" + wrong);
                wron.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                bread2 = 0;

            }

        }

    });

    idkb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int swag = random1 + random2;

            tv.setText("The Correct Answer is  " + swag + ".");

            et.setText("");
            tv.setHint("Click Next Question");
            wrong++;
            wron.setText("Wrong:" + wrong);
            wron.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));

        }
    });

}

private void list() {
    submitb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    startb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    rig = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rtv);
    wron = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wtv);
    idkb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idk);

}
```

Comment: Include the stack trace from the close

Comment: Have you added any logic to check the null or empty condition. Post that as well.

Comment: nobody used `trim()` to remove space from ends ????

Answer (score 2):

Few points to consider:

- you are setting OnClickListener on **startb** twice, is it just a typo?
- in the second onClick(), you have a condition:

  ```
  int bread2 = 0;
  if (bread2 == 0) {
      //rest of code
  }
  ```

This condition will ALWAYS be satisfied, is that what you want?

- you can check if there's nothing entered by use with the following:

  ```
  String bread = et.getText().toString();

  // check if there is any text entered by user
  if (bread.length() > 0) {
      bread2 = Integer.parseInt(bread);

      if (bread2 == swag) {
          startb.setText("Next Question");

          //the rest of the code
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm understanding you correctly, but it should be easy as:

```
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
String bread = et.getText().toString();
if (bread.length() == 0){
   // raise error dialogue
} else {
   // continue to check the parsed integer
}
```

This should all be done within your click listener.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `findViewById` on the `et` before gets its value.

By the way, you are setting `bread2` value to 0, and on the next line verifying if it's 0, i suppose it's just a test, isn't it?

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int bread2 = 0;
        if (bread2 == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "You didn't answer the question!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        int swag = random1 + random2;

        et = findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);

        String bread = et.getText().toString();
        bread2 = Integer.parseInt(bread);

        //...
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think it good practice to check text length, for example this function can help you..

```
 public boolean isEditTextEmpty(EditText input){
   if(input.getText().length() == 0)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (et.getText().length == 0 || et.gettext == null ){
        // do nothing
   } else {
       // do whatever here
   }
```

this should works fine

Comment: You should first check for **null** otherwise you will get a NPE.